# Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Intentando eliminar todos los registros de la tabla `mensajes`, excepto los últimos 40, obtengo este error:

> #1235 - Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

La versión de mi Servidor MariaDB es:

> Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Esta es mi consulta:

```
DELETE * 
FROM mensajes 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM mensajes 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 40
)
```

¿Existe alguna forma de lograr en una consulta lo que necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es mover la consulta que con el `LIMIT` a una tabla derivada.

#### Ejemplo:

```
DELETE 
FROM mensajes 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id 
        FROM mensajes 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 40
    ) AS t
)
```

#### Créditos

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124492/3791844)